# Asp.net core development on the go - can I code on my android phone?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Can I develop Asp.Net Core web solutions using some IDE running on Android? Like Visual Studio for Android, or similar?

Comment: Why would you want to develop ASP.NET on an android phone ?

Comment: I don't know of any IDEs on Android. But if you set up a CI pipeline on a Github repository, I guess you could use Githubs editor through a browser and have your CI pipeline build your solution whenever you commit a change.

Comment: Typing code on the phone is generally a terrible idea (I tried) due to your phone’s keyboard that will generally give you a very hard time. Auto correct or other completion functionality will always break your code. And most keyboards have a lack of cursor movement too.

Comment: There is no IDE capable of developing ASP.NET Core on an Android device. However, you can technically use anything that can edit text, you just don't get all the syntax highlighting and such. If you really want to develop on your Android device, your best bet is to simply get an RDP/screen sharing app and connect to a real PC.